# Android Studio: Jar library use by import line

Tags: android, github, jar, import, android-studio-import

I was reading https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/download. It said to download libraries which happened to be jar files. I've found how to add jar to my project in Android Studio. The question is

1) Can I add them to Studio so that in next projects I can use the libraries by just adding "import" line and how?

2) For the example it says "git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java.git". I don't know Git. I downloaded the example which is zip of file directory. Can I just open it in Studio without the "git clone" command and how (by the way, example contains jar libraries mentioned in point 1)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can work with project without using "git clone".
Download project archive, unpack it and open in AS with `File - New - Import Project`.